# Is it possible to access MemoryStore Fragmentation Ratio e.g in Cloud Monitoring?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-memorystore

The title pretty much says it all, but just to clarify:

Redis afaik has a performance metric *mem_fragmentation_ratio*, giving the ratio of memory used as seen by the OS (*used_memory_rss*) to memory allocated by Redis (*used_memory*).

Is it possible to find this metric (or calculate it using other existing metrics) in Cloud Monitoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no. Only the GCP support team is able to verify this metric with their internal tools :(, nevertheless, I found this [Public Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/129885927) that is requesting to add this metric to monitor the instance. I suggest you do a comment and start the issue so you can get notifications about this :)

on the other hand, about the calculation, I found this [link](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-redis-performance-metrics/#metric-to-alert-on-mem_fragmentation_ratio). It seems that the formula is:

**MemoryFragmentationRatio= Used_Memory_RSS / Used_Memory**

With the command "[info all](https://redis.io/commands/info#:%7E:text=The%20INFO%20command%20returns%20information,clients%20%3A%20Client%20connections%20section)" you can get these values.

I really hope that the aforementioned information helps you.